# Executing coding directives in the python interpreter

Tags: python

I'm using PythonQL and finding that it takes a bit of time to learn the complexities of the language, so I would like to try things out directly in the interpreter in a pythonesque way. How can I instruct the interpreter to pay attention to my coding declaration? The declaration is required to get PythonQL to understand my code. The interpreter REPL loop seems to understand the declaration by changing the prompt but it doesn't follow through with running the declaration processing. Here's some code that illustrates the problem.

```
$ pip install pythonql3
```

... output from pip here

```
$ python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 26 2018, 08:42:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> #coding: pythonql
... x = [ select x for x in range(0,2) ]
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    x = [ select x for x in range(0,2) ]
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

The python interpreter ignores the coding declaration and thus "select" bombs because it is not legal python.

However, if we run the same code from a file, everything works fine because python file processing does listen to the declaration.

```
$ cat <<EOF > x.py
> #coding: pythonql
> x = [ select x for x in range(0,2) ]
> print(x)
> EOF
$ python x.py
[0, 1]
$
```

So it would be nice to somehow direct the python interpreter to understand the coding declaration. But I haven't found a way to do that.

Comment: `select` is not valid python. The first line you've pasted is just a comment, not setting anything

Comment: yes, select is not valid python. however, select is valid pythonql, and the #coding: pythonql comment in the first line does invoke a different parser for the file. If the comment did nothing, then the python call at the end of the example would generate an error instead of an answer. Of course one must install pythonql for the example to work. I've updated the question to include this in the code.

Comment: Some more detail. PythonQL appears to use the encoding declaration to implement an extended syntax thus making "select" legal. See section 2.1.4 at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#line-structure

Comment: Shebangs only work in files, not the REPL

Comment: Interestingly, coding declarations don't work even with invoking the interpreter after loading a file with the -i option.

Comment: I don't know why the question was downvoted It's a valid and well-wwritten question.

Answer (score 1):

You're making a coding declaration. It doesn't change the interpreter of the REPL, only scripts (files)

In the standard REPL, it is interpreted as a comment.

Note, your code is the same as `list(range(2))`

You might be able to use IPython or Jupyter instead

Comment: I guess the answer is a feature require for python to accept one or more coding arguments on the command line. I'll try to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Guido Van Rosssum himself, the creator of Python, is against adding "magic commands" to REPL, as Jupyter does. So I think this will be never supported.

Comment: Well I proposed a change in the idea section of the Python discussion group. https://discuss.python.org/t/have-i-option-understand-and-accept-coding-declaration/3347

Answer (score 1):

So this is what is getting called under the hood - https://github.com/pythonql/pythonql/blob/master/pythonql/codec/register.py#L28-L29 - what you need to do is get that encoding set as your console encoding for the REPL. Probably doable by a couple of function calls after startup. I don't have the invocation handy though, sorry.

We'd probably accept a feature to allow setting the repl coding directly via a env variable though, because the coding feature is currently asymmetric vs the console as this shows.

Comment: Thanks - I think this answer is the best answer. I disagree about using environment variables since it just “continues” the asymmetry. But that’s a matter of taste I guess.